# Trouble creating a remap that compiles the current open latex file along with one other latex file in the current directory

Tags: vimrc, vimscript

I am working with latex files. 
I want to have a normal mode remapping which compiles my current file and a latex file named main.tex (both in my current working directory). The  command to compile is:

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode
```

To get the behavior I want, I have tried:

```
nnoremap <leader>cv :w \|! pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %  <CR><CR> \|! pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode main.tex
```

This doesn't work however. I get the following results:

[image]

Then after hitting enter I get:

[image]

and finally, all this "log " info gets written to my file as shown:
[image]

I just want these compile commands to happen in the background and of course have nothing written into the file.

Is my

```
:w
```

at the start to blame possibly. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/)

Comment: And I think the issue is `\|! pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode main.tex` after the `<CR><CR>` looks like a typo